# Is Galaxy Tab S4 incompatible with ARCore?

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore

It is not possible to install Google AR Core on Galaxy Tab S4 SM-T835. Google Play is showing the message that application is not compatible with device.  (anyway it is showed as AR Core compatible).
https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices

We can't even install any of ARCore compatible applications that way.
The device has been brough for development and testing of ARCore applications.

We have just received an answer from local Samsung comunity support, that it's not an Samsung application and that way the Samsung has no possibility to change it, and it's needed to contact an developer, in that case a google corporation. They are sorry, but they couldn't help me in that case.

Should we choose another device by different manufacturer (aka avoid Samsung devices) to get compatibility with ARCore? And what device is absolutely compatible one?

Comment: I see the device listed on the website. I think you should open a support ticket [here](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues).

Answer (score 0):

At the moment `Samsung Galaxy Tab S4` is compatible with ARCore 1.8. And it requires `Android 8.0` or later. Galaxy Tab S4 SM-T835 model has all the necessary sensors: Gyroscope, Accelerometer, Compass, and RGB-camera.

There was some compatibility's delay for Samsung gadgets but now everything works perfectly.

Hope this helps.